# Powershell: Use a variable to reference a property of $_ in a script block

Tags: powershell, closures, scriptblock

```
$var =@(  @{id="1"; name="abc"; age="1"; },
          @{id="2"; name="def"; age="2"; } );
$properties = @("ID","Name","Age") ;
$format = @();
foreach ($p  in $properties)
{
    $format += @{label=$p ; Expression = {$_.$p}} #$_.$p is not working!
}
$var |% { [PSCustomObject]$_  } | ft $format
```

In the above example, I want to access each object's property through a variable name. But it cannot work as expected. So in my case, how to make

```
Expression = {$_.$p}
```

working?

Comment: My bad, suppose the "properties" contains different property names. Please see the edited $properties.

Comment: You can just use `Expression = $p`.

Comment: Or you can use `Expression = &{$p=$p; {$_.$p}.GetNewClosure()}`, if you really want script block for `Expression`.

Comment: @PetSerAl - I don't see GetNewClosure() working in this scenario unless you re-factor it to a nested loop. As it stands it's going to have problems closing over either $_ or $p, depending on where you do the closure.

Comment: @mjolinor It work fine for me. Can you show any evidence, that it not working properly in this scenario?

Comment: @PetSerAl - I didn't test it before I made the comment, but it does appear to work. I wouldn't have expected the closure to work over $_, but apparently it does leave that as a literal string.  Learn something new every day. As an aside, when Get-NewClosure() was first introduce and I tested it against [scriptblock]::create(). Oddly, it took longer to re-close an existing script block than it did to create a brand new one using an expandable string.

Comment: @mjolinor *Oddly, it took longer to re-close an existing script block than it did to create a brand new one using an expandable string.* For which script block size? I expect `GetNewClosure()` taking same time independent of script block size. While `[ScriptBlock]::Create()` should take more time as script block size increasing.

Comment: @PetSerAl - It was admittedly a small script block (probably less than 20 characters and involving only a single variable).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>The OP's code and this answer use **PSv3+** syntax. Casting a hashtable to `[pscustomobject]` is not supported in PSv2, but you can replace `[pscustomobject] $_` with `New-Object PSCustomObject -Property $_`.</sup>

As in many cases in the past, [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) has provided the answer in terse (but very helpful) comments on the question; let me elaborate:

Your **problem is *not* that you're using a variable (`$p`) to access a property *per se***, which *does* work (e.g., `$p = 'Year'; Get-Date | % { $_.$p }`).

Instead, the problem is that **`$p` in script block `{ $_.$p }` isn't evaluated until *later***, in the context of the `Format-Table` call, which means that **the same, fixed value is used for all input objects** - namely the value of `$p` *at that point* (which happens to be the last value that was assigned to `$p` in the `foreach` loop).

The cleanest and most generic solution is to call **`.GetNewClosure()`** on the script block to **bind `$p` in the script block to the *then-current*, loop-iteration-specific value**.

```bash
$format += @{ Label = $p; Expression = { $_.$p }.GetNewClosure() }
```

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.scriptblock.getnewclosure(v=vs.85).aspx) (emphasis added; *update*: the quoted passage has since been removed, but still applies):

> In this case, the new script block is closed over the ***local* variables** in the scope that the closure is defined in. In other words, **the current values of the *local* variables are captured and enclosed inside the script block** that is bound to the module.

Note that *automatic* variable `$_` is undefined inside the `foreach` loop (PowerShell defines it only in certain contexts as the input object at hand, such as in script blocks passed to cmdlets in a pipeline), so it remains *unbound*, as desired.

**Caveats**:

- While `.GetNewClosure()` as used above is convenient, it has the inefficiency drawback of invariably capturing *all* local variables, not just the one(s) needed; also, the returned script block runs in a dynamic (in-memory) module created for the occasion.
- A **more efficient alternative** that avoids this problem - and notably also **avoids a *bug***  in *Windows PowerShell* in which the closure over the local variables can *break*, namely when the enclosing script / function has a  ***parameter* with *validation attributes* such as `[ValidateNotNull()]` *and* that parameter is *not bound* (no value is passed)**<sup>[1]</sup> - is the following, significantly more complex expression <sup>Tip of the hat again to PetSerAl, and Burt_Harris's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24766059/45375)</sup>:

  ```bash
  $format += @{ Label = $p; Expression = & { $p = $p; { $_.$p }.GetNewClosure() } }
  ```

  - `& { ... }` creates a *child scope* with its own local variables.
  - `$p = $p` then creates a *local* `$p` variable from its *inherited* value.
    To generalize this approach, *you must include such a statement for each variable referenced in the script block*.
  - `{ $_.$p }.GetNewClosure()` then outputs a script block that closes over the child scope's local variables (just `$p` in this case).
  - The bug was originally reported as [GitHub issue #3144](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3144) and has since [been fixed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/3149/files) in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) (but won't be fixed in *Windows PowerShell*).
- For *simple* cases, [mjolinor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42189450/45375) may do: it *indirectly* creates a script block *via an expanded string* that incorporates the then-current `$p` value *literally*, but note that the approach is *tricky to generalize*, because just stringifying a variable value doesn't generally guarantee that it works as part of PowerShell *source code* (which the expanded string must evaluate to in order to be converted to a script block).

To put it all together:

```bash
# Sample array of hashtables.
# Each hashtable will be converted to a custom object so that it can
# be used with Format-Table.
$var = @(  
          @{id="1"; name="abc"; age="3" }
          @{id="2"; name="def"; age="4" }
       )

# The array of properties to output, which also serve as
# the case-exact column headers.
$properties = @("ID", "Name", "Age")

# Construct the array of calculated properties to use with Format-Table: 
# an array of output-column-defining hashtables.
$format = @()
foreach ($p in $properties)
{
    # IMPORTANT: Call .GetNewClosure() on the script block
    #            to capture the current value of $p.
    $format += @{ Label = $p; Expression = { $_.$p }.GetNewClosure() }
    # OR: For efficiency and full robustness (see above):
    # $format += @{ Label = $p; Expression = & { $p = $p; { $_.$p }.GetNewClosure() } }
}

$var | ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject] $_ } | Format-Table $format
```

This yields:

```
ID Name Age
-- ---- ---
1  abc  3  
2  def  4
```

as desired: the output columns use the column labels specified in `$properties` while containing the correct values.

<sup>Note how I've removed unnecessary `;` instances and replaced built-in aliases `%` and `ft` with the underlying cmdlet names for clarity. I've also assigned distinct `age` values to better demonstrate that the output is correct.</sup>

---

**Simpler solution, in this *specific* case:**

**To reference a property value *as-is*, *without transformation*, it is sufficient to use the *name* of the property as the `Expression` entry** in the calculated property (column-formatting hashtable). In other words: you do not need a `[scriptblock]` instance containing an *expression* in this case (`{ ... }`), only a `[string]` value containing the property *name*.

Therefore, the following would have worked too:

```bash
# Use the property *name* as the 'Expression' entry's value.
$format += @{ Label = $p; Expression = $p }
```

Note that this approach happens to *avoid* the original problem, because `$p` is evaluated *at the time of assignment*, so the loop-iteration-specific values are captured.

---

<sup>[1] To reproduce: `function foo { param([ValidateNotNull()] $bar) {}.GetNewClosure() }; foo` fails when `.GetNewClosure()` is called, with error `Exception calling "GetNewClosure" with "0" argument(s): "The attribute cannot be added because variable bar with value  would no longer be valid."`

That is, an attempt is made to include the *unbound* `-bar` parameter value - the `$bar` variable - in the closure, which apparently then defaults to `$null`, which violates its validation attribute.

Passing a valid `-bar` value makes the problem go away; e.g., `foo -bar ''`.

The rationale for considering this a *bug*: If the *function itself* treats `$bar` in the absence of a `-bar` parameter value as nonexistent, so should `.GetNewClosure()`.</sup>

Comment: @PetSerAl: As an aside: It seems that the attribute is only a problem in _parameters_, not variables; e.g., `[ValidateNotNull()] $o = ''`. Any idea why?

Comment: Variables can not violate validation attributes. Such violation would be caught on assignment `[ValidateNotNull()] $o = $null`, or when you try to add attribute `$o = $null; (gv o).Attributes.Add([ValidateNotNull]::new())`. But unused parameters would have default value even if it violate validation attributes. When `GetNewClosure()` capture such parameter, then it fail. It should be question about this on Stack Overflow already.

Comment: P.S.  The source code for variable capture is in a method called CaptureLocals() in https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/02b5f357a20e6dee9f8e60e3adb9025be3c94490/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/Modules/PSModuleInfo.cs

Comment: The closure bug is a tough little worm in 5.14393. I had it on the scriptblock argument of Register-ArgumentCompleter in a module. The module itself loaded and ran fine with the session or any CLI imports, but when I ran my create backup script that did Remove-Module and Import-Module -Force (to load changes), it produced this error on the "update" variable (presumably somewhere in Register-ArgumentCompleter). Could not fix it, so I just catched and suppressed it since argument completion failures are irrelevant for the backup, and I'm losing access to the system soon anyways.

Answer (score 1):

While the whole approach seems misguided for the given example, just as an exercise in making it work the key is going to be controlling variable expansion at the right time.  In your `foreach` loop, `$_` is null (`$_` is only valid in the pipeline). You need to wait until it gets to the `Foreach-Object` loop to try and evaluate it.

This seems to work with a minimum amount of refactoring:

```
$var =@(  @{id="1"; name="abc"; age="1"; },
      @{id="2"; name="def"; age="2"; } );
$properties = @("ID","Name","Age") ;
$format = @();
foreach ($p  in $properties)
{
    $format += @{label=$p ; Expression = [scriptblock]::create("`$`_.$p")} 
}
$var | % { [PSCustomObject] $_ } | ft $format
```

Creating the scriptblock from an expandable string will allow `$p` to expand for each property name.  Escaping `$_` will keep it as a literal in the string, until it's rendered as a scriptblock and then evaluated in the `ForEach-Object` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing anything inside an Array of HashTables is going to be a bit finicky, but your variable expansion is corrected like this:

```
    $var =@(  @{id="1"; name="Sally"; age="11"; },
          @{id="2"; name="George"; age="12"; } );
$properties = "ID","Name","Age"
$format = @();

$Var | ForEach-Object{
    foreach ($p  in $properties){
        $format += @{
            $p = $($_.($p))
        }
    }
}
```

You needed another loop to be able to tie it to a specific item in your array.
That being said, I think that going with an array of Objects would be a much cleaner approach - but I don't know what you're dealing with, exactly.

Comment: We (now, possibly after you answered) know that the OP wants `$format` to contain _calculated properties_ for later use with `Format-Table`, so this won't work.